# How do I migrate my registered servers in SSMS from one machine to another?

Tags: ssms

How do I migrate my registered servers in SSMS from one machine to another?

I tried copying %appdata%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell over during my profile migration, but apparently something got corrupted there, and now I don't know how to get just my registered servers (but I did keep my templates)

So now I'm nervous if I just move the RegSrvr.xml file if that's all I need to move from the other machine?

Ok, so I want to point out that I also did an export/import, and those didn't come across either. Is it because I'm trying to export/import the usernames and passwords too? :\

Note: some of the machines WERE configured to have remote IP connections, with VPNs and the like, so I've removed those from my config, done an export, and I am still having issues with the import.

I also had to follow the instructions at the foot of this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqltools/thread/1115cd55-721d-4974-99b1-d142d1e6a927 to get my SSMS to function correctly, so I pretty surely have a botched install. This may not be a solvable problem for me :\